# How can I add ScreenTip to shape (Visio) C#, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio

Tags: c#, office-interop, visio, shapesheet

How can I add screen tip to shape in visio using c# and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio
Actually I tried to use Controls Section and I followed microsoft documentation but it does not work and showing me this error: "\n\nUnexpected end of file."

here is microsoft documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/visio/tip-cell-controls-section

And here is my code in c# to change the screentip(last line for screen tip)

```
visioRectShape.get_Cells("FillForegnd").Formula = "RGB(0,102,255)";
                            visioRectShape.get_Cells("Char.Size").Formula = "10 pt";
                            visioRectShape.get_CellsU("Controls.TestName.Tip").Formula = "10 pt";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think adding a tip to controls is what you want to do. If you want a tool tip on the whole shape then add it to the Comment cell in the Miscellaneous section. You can do this like this:

```
visioRectShape.get_Cells("Comment").Formula = "\"My Text Tip\"";
```

Note the tip has double quotes inside the string of the Formula, i.e. double double quotes.
Controls are the little yellow handles which allow you to move part of a shape. Not all shapes have them. They are different from the handles which allow you resize and rotate whole shapes. Adding a tip to a control will show for just the yellow handle. If this is what you want to do you can do it like this:

```
visioRectShape.get_Cells("Controls.Row_1.Prompt").Formula = "\"Control Tip\"";
```

"Row_1" in the cell name above must be the name of a Control row in the shape.

Comment: Thanks @happyMoose it's working fine

Answer (score 1):

Ah @HappyMoose got there first so points to her/him....but since I'd virtually finished writing - the Tip cell's name is `Prompt` rather than 'Tip', which is displayed in the ShapeSheet.

```
visioRectShape.CellsU["Controls.Row_1.Prompt"].FormulaU = $"=\"MyControlHandle\"";
visioRectShape.CellsU["Comment"].FormulaU = $"=\"MyShapeComment\"";
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, it's working now @JohnGoldsmith